# issues a soap request via curl not working and server returning "Empty reply from server"

Tags: http, unix, curl, soap, libcurl

Hi i am trying to issue a post request to a soap endpoint using curl . However it dont return any thing. then following is the curl request.

```
    curl -v -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8"  --data @soap-req.xml http://192.168.123.219:8085/engage/stats
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 192.168.123.219...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.123.219 (192.168.123.219) port 8085 (#0)
> POST /engage/stats HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.123.219:8085
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 309
> 
* upload completely sent off: 309 out of 309 bytes
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.123.219 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

the following is the content of the file soap request 9 soap-req.xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eng="http://openmindnetworks.com/engage/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <eng:getCampaignStats>
         <id>f4202b29-5db5-4cec-965f-70710fcdb60d</id>
      </eng:getCampaignStats>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

however when i use a soap UI i its working fine .

appreciate if you can help me to troubleshoot

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever me make a soap request we should always add soapaction header. since it was missing there was empty response form the server.

```
curl  -H 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8'
      -H 'SOAPAction: http://openmindnetworks.com/engage/getCampaignStats'
      --data @soap-req.xml http://192.168.123.219:8085/engage/stats
```